# I need to print all unique words in an array of strings but not sure how

Tags: java

so the full program reads a story from a file and stores each word in an array of strings. After the story is read, I need to print all unique words in the story but I don't know how. Here is what I have

```
import java.util.*;
import csci1140.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Story{
    public static final void main(String[] args){
    String[] storyArray = new String[28203];

    String fileName = "MultiLineStory.txt";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("Unable to find file: " + fileName);
    }

    try{
        String input = null;            
        for(int i = 0; i < storyArray.length; i++){
            if((input = reader.readLine()) != null){
                 String fill = input;
                 storyArray[i] = fill;
            } 
           // System.out.print(storyArray[i] + " ");
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finally {
        try{
            reader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(storyArray);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("\n\nArrays.sort took " +((end - start)/1E9) + " Sec");
    distinctValues(storyArray);
}
public static boolean distinctValues(String[] array){   
int count = 0;      
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {

        if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
            count++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    return false;
 }
```

}

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Ignore the `array` and look into what a `HashSet` is.

Comment: *reads a story from a file and stores each word in an array of strings* No. This code stores each **line** of the story into the array.

Comment: Well, in the .txt file each word of the story is its own line.

Comment: Why only arrays? Can't you use collections? Please also do share a few lines of the files along with expected output.

Comment: To print all unique words you need an array for the words you have printed and two nested arrays. The outer array runs over your words. In the inner array you check first if the word is one of the unique words you have printed. If yes you do nothing. If no you add the word to the array of unique words and print it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashSet<String>` and put all elements of the array into it. Then just print them out one by one.

```
String[] allWordsArray = ...;
HashSet<String> uniqueWordsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(allWordsArray));

for (String word : uniqueWordsSet)
{
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package com;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/*to print unique words which are not repeated*/
public class UniqueWords {
    public static final void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> allWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String fileName = "C:\\TestFiles\\MultiLineStory.txt";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String input = null;            
            if((input = reader.readLine()) != null){
                String arr[] = input.split(" ");
                allWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
            } 
            System.out.println(allWords.size());
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.out.println("Unable to find file: " + fileName);
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } finally {
            try{
                reader.close();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        for(String word : allWords)
        {
            if(!map.containsKey(word))
                map.put(word, 1);
            else
                map.put(word, map.get(word)+1);
        }
        Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
        for(String key : keySet)
            if(map.get(key)==1)
                System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```